# Splitting a vector or list based on a value

Tags: r

I am trying to split the following list:

```
x <- c(1, 19, 25, 62, 38, 41, 52, 53, 60, 61,  1, 74, 72, 66, 1, 68, 5, 1)
```

What I would like to do is split the above using the number 1 as the break points.

```
x1 <- c(1, 19, 25, 62, 38, 41, 52, 53, 60, 61)
x2 <- c(1, 74, 72, 66)
x3 <- c(1, 68, 5)
```

There must be a simple method to use but I am drawing a blank and my search-fu is weak and coming up empty.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this for the language R? Or another language

Comment: R, specifically rstudio.

Comment: RStudio is not a language, but an IDE (i.e. a very fancy and useful text editor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `split` with `cumsum`:

```
x <- c(1, 19, 25, 62, 38, 41, 52, 53, 60, 61,  1, 74, 72, 66, 1, 68, 5, 1)

split(x, f=cumsum(x==1))

#> $`1`
#> [1]  1 19 25 62 38 41 52 53 60 61
#> 
#> $`2`
#> [1]  1 74 72 66
#> 
#> $`3`
#> [1]  1 68  5
#> 
#> $`4`
#> [1] 1
```